# trouble in connecting to opendaylight using python API

Tags: python, mininet, opendaylight

I tried this code in python to connect to controller:

```
from mininet.net import Mininet

from mininet.node import Controller, RemoteController, OVSKernelSwitch, UserSwitch

from mininet.cli import CLI

from mininet.log import setLogLevel

from mininet.link import Link, TCLink

 

def topology():

        net = Mininet( controller=RemoteController, link=TCLink, switch=OVSKernelSwitch )

 

        # Add hosts and switches

        h1 = net.addHost( 'h1', ip="10.0.1.10/24", mac="00:00:00:00:00:01" )

        h2 = net.addHost( 'h2', ip="10.0.2.10/24", mac="00:00:00:00:00:02" )

        r1 = net.addHost( 'r1')

        s1 = net.addSwitch( 's1')

        s2 = net.addSwitch( 's2')

        c0 = net.addController( 'c0', controller=RemoteController, ip='192.168.19.132', port=6633 )

 

        net.addLink( r1, s1 )

        net.addLink( r1, s2 )

        net.addLink( h1, s1 )

        net.addLink( h2, s2 )

        net.build()

        c0.start()

        s1.start( [c0] )

        s2.start( [c0] )

        r1.cmd("ifconfig r1-eth0 0")

        r1.cmd("ifconfig r1-eth1 0")

        r1.cmd("ifconfig r1-eth0 hw ether 00:00:00:00:01:01")

        r1.cmd("ifconfig r1-eth1 hw ether 00:00:00:00:01:02")

        r1.cmd("ip addr add 10.0.1.1/24 brd + dev r1-eth0")

        r1.cmd("ip addr add 10.0.2.1/24 brd + dev r1-eth1")

        r1.cmd("echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward")

        h1.cmd("ip route add default via 10.0.1.1")

        h2.cmd("ip route add default via 10.0.2.1")

        s1.cmd("ovs-ofctl add-flow s1 priority=1,arp,actions=flood")

        s1.cmd("ovs-ofctl add-flow s1 priority=65535,ip,dl_dst=00:00:00:00:01:01,actions=output:1")

        s1.cmd("ovs-ofctl add-flow s1 priority=10,ip,nw_dst=10.0.1.0/24,actions=output:2")

        s2.cmd("ovs-ofctl add-flow s2 priority=1,arp,actions=flood")

        s2.cmd("ovs-ofctl add-flow s2 priority=65535,ip,dl_dst=00:00:00:00:01:02,actions=output:1")

        s2.cmd("ovs-ofctl add-flow s2 priority=10,ip,nw_dst=10.0.2.0/24,actions=output:2")

 

        print ("*** Running CLI")

        CLI( net )

 

        print ("*** Stopping network")

        net.stop()

      

if __name__ == '__main__':

    setLogLevel( 'info' )

    topology()
```

but when I check dlux in browser it doesn't show any nodes.
if I use CLI and set the topology using sudo mn  and give it the ip of my controller then it works.
why doesn't it work with python?
I used ubuntu 20.04 and my opendaylight version is nitrogen.

thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a fix for this? I am running into a similar issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific with defining your remote controller. If you have the controller installed on the same Linux host as Mininet had been installed on, then you need to define you controller IP and port like below. I used this script with ODL Lithium version and it worked with no problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.link import TCIntf
from mininet.node import CPULimitedHost
from mininet.topolib import TreeTopo
from mininet.util import custom, quietRun
from mininet.log import setLogLevel, info
from mininet.cli import CLI
from mininet.node import RemoteController
from mininet.link import TCLink
setLogLevel( 'info' )

net = Mininet( link=TCLink )
c0 = net.addController(name='c0' ,
                             controller=RemoteController ,
                             ip='localhost',
                             port=6653) // # the port for newer versions might be different
s1 = net.addSwitch('s1', protocols='OpenFlow13')
s2 = net.addSwitch('s2', protocols='OpenFlow13')


net.addLink(s1, s2, delay='50ms')
net.addLink(s1, s2, bw=0.2)
net.addLink(s1, s2)    

net.start()
CLI(net)
```